# Need to pass a parameter to a procedure with no arguments

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

We do run a business application which allow us to run stored procedures to do several jobs including copying data from 1 table to another. The problem is this application don't allow to pass dynamic or user values. you have to predefine the values of the parameter in the job which makes it really static.

Is there a way to pass value to a stored procedure without using parameter?

Comment: You are aware that you question makes very little sense. Are you looking to pass a dynamic list of parameters (so 0, 1, 2...p number of parameters0? How would the sp know what to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way would be to use parameters. However, I guess you can insert data into a table through some ad hoc sql and have the stored proc read it.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can get the user values and store it in a table. Also the parameters(now you can use temp values) can be got inside the Stored Procedure by using any distinct column in your user values table.